# flex/AIR based SLD generator?

Tags: open-source-gis, geoserver, cartography, sld

Styling layers in GeoServer can be tedious to say the least. While Styler can relieve some of that tedium, it doesn't yet work in chrome. It can wreck existing styles if not carefully used and still involves a fair amount of manual labor.

I was wondering if there were any flex/AIR SLD generators floating around?

Comment: ...or even, visual SLD tools that work better than the "imagining it in my head" technique I'm on now?  Web-based or otherwise.

Comment: a tag for geoserver would be nice too ;-)

Comment: There is one now: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoserver

Comment: removed gis tag; it's "meta" for this site: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 3):

Note that OpenLayers now supports ([as of Aug 2](http://trac.openlayers.org/changeset/10560)) reading and writing of multiple symbolizers per rule and multiple FeatureTypeStyle elements per UserStyle.  This greatly increases the SLD elements that we can round trip through the OpenLayers SLD parser (and consequently, through Styler).

I've also recently added support for reading and writing custom GeoServer vendor options in Styler.  While not yet exposed to through the GUI, at least these will be preserved if you are editing your SLD by hand and with Styler.

I also just confirmed that the latest Styler works with Chrome (please [send word](http://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/new) if you are still seeing Chrome issues).

I grant that styling with Styler is still very tedious.  We'll continue to work on reducing the tedium.  If you are interested in trying out the latest Styler, see the OpenGeo Suite [community downloads page](http://opengeo.org/community/suite/download/) (version 2.1.1 and above have all the fixes mentioned above).

I know this is not entirely relevant to your search for a flash based solution, but I thought some updated information on Styler was worthwhile.

Comment: Tim, is that part of the new OpenGeo community edition or should I mention that as well.

Comment: thanks tim. i haven't seen anything about "new" editions of styler on the geoserver site. is it available as separate d/l?

Comment: to be clear-er, we build most of our front ends w/flex/AIR so having a flash-based tool would fit in nicely & we can probably contribute something to it. the SLD bits scare me away from doing it myself :-(

Comment: Styler is bundled up with the GeoServer webapp in the Suite.  You can always get the source (link on same download page) and build it yourself, but the simplest way to try it out quickly would be with the full install.

Answer (score 1):

You can use uDig to create SLDs for Geoserver.  The uDig's SLD functionality seems a bit buggy though.  Here is a tutorial for generating SLDs via uDig for use in Geoserver:

http://mballingercapstone.web.officelive.com/uDig.aspx

Answer (score 1):

fwiw, if you have ArcGIS and need to export an SLD for your layers or the map itself, you can use Arc2Earth (free version too). We built the functionality for a client who needed the ArcMap marker symbols exported and embedded in the SLD

cheers
brian

[more info here](http://bit.ly/bG8T90)

Comment: There is no more free version.

Answer (score 1):

AtlasStyler http://en.geopublishing.org/AtlasStyler is IMHO the most powerful OGC SLD editor. 
It is a desktop application based on Java/Swing. It allows to edit you own symbols, save and load them to you local database, or load them from an online database. These symbols can then be re-used in more complex tasks, like classification by quantiles or unique values. Supports classes for missing data.

AtlasStyler 1.6 SLD editor is based on Geotools 2.6.5, so it's 99,9% compatible with Geoserver 2.0.2 (which is based on same Geotools version). 
AtlasStyler Version 1.6 can style Shapefiles, WFS and PostGIS. Upcoming version 1.7 (available in testing) has a lot of new features in AtlasStyler, like Min- and Max- Scale.

AtlasStyler runs on Linux, Mac and even Windows!

Answer (score 0):

Qgis also has a plugin for making SLD from your current map composition. I have used it to style layers in Geoserver.

The plugin spits out the XML which you can then save or paste into the appropriate location.

Comment: yeah qGIS works but if i remember correctly it only handles unique classifications.

Comment: The QGIS plugin is extremely limited

Answer (score 0):

I had a related need of taking arcgis symbology to geoserver. The way I worked it out is documented in [Creating summary table of symbology of all datasets in multiple MXDs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27807/create-a-summary-table-of-the-symbology-of-all-datasets-in-multiple-mxds) and related questions. If you have ArcGIS (or get QGIS) I would create the symbology in them (the tools are graphic based rather than text based so it's easier than coding). QGIS will let you save the symbology as an sld. If you do it via ArcGIS you need to use the free version of Arc2Earth and then export the symbology as sld (simple 2-click process).

I hope this works for you.