# Batch converting .lyr to .qml?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, sld, layer-file, qml

I am looking for ways to make .lyr files usable in QGIS. It appears that they can be converted into an .sld file in ArcMap but according to one of the posts, they only store symbology and do not point to the data itself. Do you know of a way to make the .lyr files into their equivalent (.qml?) in QGIS? These are the sources I have reviewed: 
[Adding Layerfiles (.lyr) to QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24300/adding-layerfiles-lyr-to-qgis)

[Converting ArcGIS layer style to Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/converting-arcgis-layer-style-to-styled-layer-descriptor-sld-file)

[Can QGIS automatically load an SLD with a Shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33965/can-qgis-automatically-load-an-sld-with-a-shapefile)

[Does QGIS have the equivalent of ArcGIS's Layer (*.LYR) file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88834/does-qgis-have-the-equivalent-of-arcgiss-layer-lyr-file)

Comment: see https://north-road.com/2019/02/04/announcing-our-slyr-funding-drive/